# Emulate VMware vswitch on KVM

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, vlan, keyboard-video-mouse, vswitch

I'm wondering how I would go about emulating how a standard vswitch works in KVM.

In VMware you have the following:
vmnic -> vswitch(tagged) -> port group (untagged)

So all traffic going to the standard vswitch is tagged and the tags are stripped at each port group.

The configuration on the port group is flexible in the sense that I can modify the untagged vlan on the port group without having to impact networking or restart services for changes to take effect. Additionally the config remains persistent across host reboots (this is important)

How can I implement similar functionality on KVM So that it exhibits similar behavior?

Comment: Not to repeat myself, I just typed an answer to this yesterday:
http://serverfault.com/questions/585774/persistent-network-configuration-using-kvm-and-libvirt

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do what you need with vlan tags on the bridges then maybe http://openvswitch.org/ although it seems a little overkill

Comment: Does openvswitch allow the ability to run simple commands against it like "set this port to untagged on vlan 5" and then commit it to memory? Is there anyway to achieve this with bridges?